# How to import from CSV and add containing numbers together?

Tags: arrays, csv, autoit, addition

I'm having issues reading a CSV file to then add containing numbers together.

### main.au3

```
$billsRawData1 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 2)
$billsArray1 = StringSplit($billsRawData1, ",")

$billsRawData2 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 3)
$billsArray2 = StringSplit($billsRawData2, ",")

$billsRawData3 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 4)
$billsArray3 = StringSplit($billsRawData3, ",")

$billsRawData4 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 5)
$billsArray4 = StringSplit($billsRawData4, ",")

$billsRawData5 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 6)
$billsArray5 = StringSplit($billsRawData5, ",")

$billsRawData6 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 7)
$billsArray6 = StringSplit($billsRawData6, ",")

$billsRawData7 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 8)
$billsArray7 = StringSplit($billsRawData7, ",")

$billsRawData8 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 9)
$billsArray8 = StringSplit($billsRawData8, ",")

$billsRawData9 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 10)
$billsArray9 = StringSplit($billsRawData9, ",")

$billsRawData10 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 11)
$billsArray10 = StringSplit($billsRawData10, ",")

$billsRawData11 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 12)
$billsArray11 = StringSplit($billsRawData11, ",")

$billsRawData12 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 13)
$billsArray12 = StringSplit($billsRawData12, ",")

$billsRawData13 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 14)
$billsArray13 = StringSplit($billsRawData13, ",")

$billsRawData14 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 15)
$billsArray14 = StringSplit($billsRawData14, ",")

$billsRawData15 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 16)
$billsArray15 = StringSplit($billsRawData15, ",")

$billsRawData16 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 17)
$billsArray16 = StringSplit($billsRawData16, ",")

$billsRawData17 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 18)
$billsArray17 = StringSplit($billsRawData17, ",")

$billsRawData18 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 19)
$billsArray18 = StringSplit($billsRawData18, ",")

$billsRawData19 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 20)
$billsArray19 = StringSplit($billsRawData19, ",")

$billsRawData20 = FileReadLine(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 21)
$billsArray20 = StringSplit($billsRawData20, ",")

$total = $billsArray1[3] + $billsArray2[3]; + $billsArray3[3] + $billsArray4[3] + $billsArray5[3] + $billsArray6[3] + $billsArray7[3] + $billsArray8[3] + $billsArray9[3] + $billsArray10[3] + $billsArray11[3] + $billsArray12[3] + $billsArray13[3] + $billsArray14[3] + $billsArray15[3]; + $billsArray16[3] + $billsArray17[3] + $billsArray18[3] + $billsArray19[3] + $billsArray20[3]
MsgBox(0, "", $total)
```

### test.csv

```
,,,
10/04/2015, Internet,$40 , Monthly
10/07/2015, Gas,$80 , Monthly
10/01/2015, Cable,$60 , Monthly
10/27/2015, Storage,$50 , Monthly
10/30/2015,School,$150 , Monthly
10/18/2015,Rent,$750 ,Monthly
```

test.csv contains variable amount of rows. I'm trying to add the value in the third column. I read each line into a variable and split that into an array (`$billsArray1[3]` returns `$40`). I then add these variables together, but it returns `0` for `$total`.

1) Why is `$total` returning `0` instead of the total?

2) How to create a loop to assign the variables (so I don't need to create new variables for each line, as I don't know how many lines there will be)? Note* it always skips the first line so it starts at line 2.

3) How to create another loop to add the data in the third column together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't create a separate array. I'd just loop over the file, grab the 3rd entry, strip everything that isn't a number (like `$`) and then add that to the total...

```
$file = FileOpen(@AppDataDir & "\testDir\test.csv", 0)
$total = 0

While 1
    $line = FileReadLine($file)
    If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop

    ;Get the 3rd "token" and strip everything that is not a number.
    $bill = StringRegExpReplace(StringSplit($line, ',')[3], "[^\d]", "")

    ;Add current bill to total.
    $total = $total + $bill
WEnd
FileClose($file)

MsgBox(0, "Total", $total)
```